# Which is the correct page object model design and why?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework, page-objects, testing-framework

### Issue:

The target webpage has many buttons in the page and adding separate abstraction for each method like , click button1 , button2 etc feels like unnecessary and just creates additional lines of code.

So to address this the below approaches where suggested:

**Approach 1:**

Create a map of element and pass the element name as key

**Page Object:**

```
package page_objects;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import driversetup.TestBaseClass;

public class homepage extends TestBaseClass {

    private Map<String, WebElement> elements = new HashMap<String, WebElement>();
    
    public homepage() {
        driver.get().get("https://courses.ultimateqa.com/users/sign_in");
    }
    
    public void initializeElements() {
        elements.put("password_field", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"password\"]")));
        elements.put("email_field", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"email\"]")));
    }

    public homepage inputText(String field, String value) {
        elements.get(field).sendKeys(value);
        return this;
    }

}
```

**Test case:**

```
package test_suites;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Utils.excelParcer;
import driversetup.TestBaseClass;
import page_objects.homepage;

public class Testcase1 extends TestBaseClass {

    homepage homepage;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        initializeTestBase();
        homepage = new homepage();
        homepage.initializeElements();
    }

    @Test(description = "Test case 1 assert True")
    public void loginPageTitleTest2() {
        homepage.inputText("email_field", "test").inputText("password_field", "text2").click(homepage.signin);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Approach 2:**

Make elements public and pass the element to the method

**Page Object:**

```
package page_objects;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import driversetup.TestBaseClass;

public class homepage extends TestBaseClass {

    public WebElement email;
    public WebElement password;
    public WebElement signin;
    
    public homepage() {
        driver.get("https://courses.ultimateqa.com/users/sign_in");
    }
    
    public void initializeElements() {
        email= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"password\"]"));
        password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"email\"]"));
        submit= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"submit\"]"));
    }

    public homepage inputText(WebElement field, String value) {
        field.sendKeys(value);
        return this;
    }

    public homepage click(WebElement field) {
        field.click();
        return this;
    }

}
```

**Test case:**

```
    package test_suites;
    
    import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import Utils.excelParcer;
    import driversetup.TestBaseClass;
    import page_objects.homepage;
    
    public class Testcase1 extends TestBaseClass {
    
        homepage homepage;
    
        @BeforeMethod
        public void setUp() {
            initializeTestBase();
            homepage = new homepage();
            homepage.initializeElements();
        }
    
        @Test(description = "Test case 1 assert True")
        public void loginPageTitleTest2() {
            homepage.inputText(homepage.email, "test").inputText(homepage.password, "text2").click(homepage.signin);
        }
    
        @AfterMethod
        public void tearDown() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    
    }
```

### Question

Which of the two is better , and if both are not suggested why would making webelement private and create separate methods for each element recommended

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you are coupling your tests with the page object through a convention on the strings "email_field" and "password_field"

If a change is not done correctly, you would discover it only at run time. Not so good.

In the second case, you are coupling through the attributes. Erroneous changes would be catch at compilation time, but, nonetheless, you would have to change every instance of the attributes in the tests and, worse of all, assume that your test would not mess up the meaning of each attribute (because they are public).

What you can do is to create an object for the credentials pass it to a function of your page object, leaving its internals hidden.

The test:

```
@Test(description = "Test case 1 assert True")
public void loginPageTitleTest2() {
    Credentials credentials = CredentialsFactory().password("text2").email("test").build();
    homepage.signIn(credentials);
}
```

And the page object:

```
public Homepage signIn(Credentials credentials) {
    findEmailField().sendKeys(credentials.getEmail());
    findPasswordField().sendKeys(credentials.getPassword());
    findSubmitButton().click();
    return this;
}
```

Then the `findX()` functions can be done as you wish. I would suggest searching to the element only at the time, if you don't see necessity of optimizing it at the moment ("early optimization is the root of all evil):

```
private WebElement findEmailField() {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"email\"]"));
}
```

Or you can have a single function for searching elements: `findComponent`

```
private WebElement findComponent(String componentName) {
    return driver.findElement(findLocatorFor(component));
}

private By findLocatorFor(String componentName) {
    return components[componentName];
}

// Constructor, where you have the map of element name and its locator
public HomePage() {
    components = Map.ofEntries(
                       entry(EMAIL, By.xpath("//input[@type=\"email\"]")),
                       entry(...));
}

// Some constants to avoid duplicating element name as string
private final String EMAIL = "email"
...

public Homepage signIn(Credentials credentials) {
    findComponent(EMAIL).sendKeys(credentials.getEmail());
    findComponent(PASSWORD).sendKeys(credentials.getPassword());
    findComponent(SUBMIT).click();
    return this;
}
```

This way you just need to keep in sync that every constant that is used by a public function to locate elements actually have a locator on the `components` map, but you can be sure that the locators won't be changed outside your object because the `components` map can be private.

Comment: my question is about findEmailField() , you have method for each field .

Comment: The second mentioned method in this question is same as the first method  mentioned in question . I was wondering what was the draw back of the two approaches ,

Comment: i agree to first point that passing string is not ideal

Comment: thats why approach two was mentioned,  but the appraoch you mentioned requires defining new contant fields thats again an overhead

Comment: findXField is one option. If you don't have to have functions for each element, you can go with the map approach on the end. The advantage over the Method 2 is that the only entry point to your object is the signIn method, thus your internal structure is hidden and can be refactored with affecting the clients.

Comment: "I was wondering what was the drawback of the two approaches" - I answered at the first few paragraphs. Do the explanations make sense?

Comment: "you mentioned requires defining new contant fields thats again an overhead" - it's one way of doing that. Overhead for the computer is none, because strings are constants in Java, so declaring a constant or repeating the string is the same. If you can choose to either. You can also choose to have a private Enum class alongside the page object, so the latter doesn't get polluted with the constant definitions. In Method 2 you have to repeat the attribute name every time it's used on the tests, which tend to grow in number while the page object for the Home Page is always just one place.

Comment: Hi the first paragraph make sense , but in the pageobject example you have findemailfield().sendkeys(). The main question was why we need an abstract method like findemailfield() . Why can't it be just this.email.sendKeys() , where email is the variable containing the element

Comment: why defining elements as public as in approach to not recommended , could you make your answer more clear by separating it under different headings

Comment: "Why can't it be just this.email.sendKeys() , where email is the variable containing the element" -> This would require this.email to be a initialized WebElement, as you did on initElements. You could do it, and you would get an slightly faster page object if you call it many times. (Continue)

Comment: (Continuing) The problem with this optimization is that (1) it requires people to remember to call initElements and (2) it requires that the three elements being foundable when initElements is called. The approach of searching at the time of use will not have such assumptions, making your page object more flexible to the behavior of the SUT: Only if you really can't continue with your test it will break, rather than break if one of all those assumptions are not fulfilled. Both approaches are ok, you just have to pick what fits better to your context. Nonetheless, they don't require public attr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120967/discussion-between-joao-farias-and-pdhide).